# Will caller_locations[...].path always include $PROGRAM_NAME?

Tags: ruby

Can I safely assume that `caller_locations[i].path == $PROGRAM_NAME` will return true for some `i`, or can there be cases where none of the caller locations return `$PROGRAM_NAME` (e.g. hard links / symlinks / some convoluted require case)?

Comment: I just ran `caller_locations.map(&:path).include?($PROGRAM_NAME)` in IRB and got false.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe. I'm just trying to find the closest call frame that originates in $PROGRAM_NAME, regardless of whether it's in a method definition or top level. This seemed like the simplest way to do it.